# crontab error "lstat: No such file or directory", after quit sudo crontab -e, without cron job modification

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I checked list of my cronjobs, using this command:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

After finished, I quit using :q vim command.

```
:q
```

After that, vi/vim editor successfully exit, but this error occurred:

```
lstat: No such file or directory
```

This is only happened, if I do it without modification.

How to know the cause of this problem?

Comment: @anx no, it is standard ubuntu instalation. What I'm worried is if my server infected by virus or malware.